# How can I make a diagram like the following in LateX?

Tags: tables

I would like to make a diagram similar to the following, with a row of bordered boxes. I also need to insert the up arrows aligned to the correct cells, with the correct description.  How can I do this in LateX?

[image: Example of Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with basic LaTeX, explicitly with `blkarray` and `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{array, blkarray}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\BAextrarowheight}{2pt}
\makeatletter
\addtolength{\BA@colsep}{1pt}
\makeatother
\begin{blockarray}{*{7}{c}}
\begin{block}{|*{7}{c|}}
\BAhline
 & &\makebox[0pt]{A} & \makebox[0pt]{B} & \makebox[0pt]{C}& & \\
 \BAhline
 \end{block}
  & & \makebox[0pt]{$\stackrel{\uparrow}{\text{\scriptsize root\vphantom{l}}}$} & & \makebox[0pt]{$\stackrel{\uparrow}{\text{\scriptsize tail}}$}
\end{blockarray}

\begin{blockarray}{*{7}{c}}
\begin{block}{|*{7}{c|}}
\BAhline
 & & & \makebox[0pt]{B} & \makebox[0pt]{C}& & \\
 \BAhline
 \end{block}
  & & & \makebox[0pt]{$\stackrel{\uparrow}{\text{\scriptsize root\vphantom{l}\ }}$} & \makebox[0pt]{$\stackrel{\uparrow}{\text{\ \scriptsize tail}}$}
\end{blockarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer was very helpful. Just a slight note, you put "room" instead of "root" (but I was able to figure out how to change that in my document). Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I misread – or maybe it was a *lapsus calami* (I was thinking there was not enough space for two consecutive annotations… I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! `\if` you are using Ti*k*Z it is straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\iffilled
\newcommand{\Diagram}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0em,#1]
\global\filledfalse
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#2}
{\draw (\Y*1.5em,0) rectangle ++ (1.5em,1.5em) node[midway]{\X};
\ifx\X\empty
\iffilled
\draw[latex-] (\Y*1.5em-0.75em,0) --++(0,-1em) node[below,font=\tiny] {tail};
\fi
\global\filledfalse
\else
\unless\iffilled
\draw[latex-] (\Y*1.5em+0.75em,0) --++(0,-1em) node[below,font=\tiny] {root};
\fi
\global\filledtrue
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
Bla bla
\[\Diagram{,,A,B,C,,}\]
bla bla
\[\Diagram{,,,B,C,,}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]